# Unable to dynamically reset the maximum height of widgets in a QSplitter

Tags: python, pyside

I'd like to have a `QSplitterHandle` resize **only** the widget above it, by:

1. Initially fixing the maximum and minimum height of all the widgets (`QFrame`'s actually) in the `QSplitter`.
2. On `QSplitterHandle::mousePressEvent` "increase the" the maximum height, and on `QSplitterHandle::mouseReleaseEvent` reset the maximum height to the current.

Code

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

# Custom Splitter Handle
class SplitterHandle(QtGui.QSplitterHandle):
   QWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT = 1000

   def __init__(self, index , orientation, parent):
      super(SplitterHandle , self).__init__(orientation, parent)
      self.index = index

   def getWidget( self ):
      return self.splitter().widget( self.index )

   # Remove height restriction on corresponding widget when dragging starts
  def mousePressEvent(self ,event ):
     widget = self.getWidget()
     widget.setMinimumHeight( 100 ) # FIX
     widget.setMaximumHeight( self.QWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT )
     return QtGui.QSplitterHandle.mousePressEvent(self,event)

  # Freeze height of corresponding widget after dragging has ends
  def mouseReleaseEvent(self ,event ):
     widget = self.getWidget()
     widget.setMinimumHeight( widget.height() ) # FIX
     widget.setMaximumHeight( widget.height() )
     return QtGui.QSplitterHandle.mousePressEvent(self,event)

# Custom Splitter
class Splitter(QtGui.QSplitter):
   def __init__( self , orientation , parent = None):
      super(Splitter , self).__init__(orientation,parent)
      self.orientation = orientation

   def createHandle( self):
      return SplitterHandle( self.count() , self.orientation , self )      


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Example, self).__init__()
      hbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

      frame1 = QtGui.QFrame()
      frame1.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
      frame1.setMinimumHeight( 100 )
      frame1.setMaximumHeight( 100 )
      frame1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");

      frame2 = QtGui.QFrame()
      frame2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
      frame2.setMinimumHeight( 100 ) 
      frame2.setMaximumHeight( 100 )
      frame2.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;");

      frame3 = QtGui.QFrame()
      frame3.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
      frame3.setMinimumHeight( 100 ) 
      frame3.setMaximumHeight( 100 )
      frame3.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;");

      frame4 = QtGui.QFrame()
      frame4.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
      frame4.setMinimumHeight( 100 ) 
      frame4.setMaximumHeight( 100 )
      frame4.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;");

      # The "absorber"
      frame5 = QtGui.QFrame()
      frame5.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");

      ########################

      splitter = Splitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

      splitter.addWidget(frame1)
      splitter.addWidget(frame2)
      splitter.addWidget(frame3)
      splitter.addWidget(frame4)
      splitter.addWidget(frame5)

      splitter.setChildrenCollapsible( False )
      hbox.addWidget(splitter)  

      self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 600)
      self.setWindowTitle('--Splitter--')
      self.show()

def main():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = Example()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

See application screenshot. The problem is that the attempts to dynamically reset the widget heights fail.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying the maximum size to an incorrect widget caused because you are passing an inappropriate index. The solution is to pass it `self.count()-1`:

```
def createHandle( self):
    return SplitterHandle(self.count()-1, self.orientation , self)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it when I get home. Do you think using size policies is a better solution or is feasible. (I'll give it a try when I get home.)

Comment: @Olumide Actually I do not know.

Comment: I guess it's a design question. Size policies will allow indefinitely resizing the widget to crazy extents. A combination of both might be a better solution. I'll post my findings shortly.

Comment: Size policies don't seem to work. I cannot find a size policy that, all by itself, prevents a widget from being resized.